# Dynamically Building a List of Func<t,t> - then applying to a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4, delegates

Not sure if this is the best approach, however here are my thoughts

I am using Entity Framework Data Model v 4.1 - i'm trying to build a where statement dynamically so that I dont have to query the db everytime, instead i can build a "list of" conditionals, then apply them all at once so the db is only queryed once as opposed to everytime i add my new conditional - if that makes sense...

here is what i have

```
List<Func<Order, bool>> orderFunctions = new List<Func<Order, bool>>();
if (this.LoggedInUser.UserId == 9)
{
Func<Order, bool> deleg = o => o.Status.Equals(OrderStatus.NewOrder);
orderFunctions.Add(deleg);
}
else if (this.LoggedInUser.UserId == 22)
{
Func<Order, bool> deleg = o => o.AssignedToUserId.Equals(22);
orderFunctions.Add(deleg);
}
List<Orders> orders = Entities.Orders.Where( Some How Apply my Order Functions List Here ).ToList();
```

I'm not sure if i'm even taking the right approach here - hopefully this makes sense - any guidance, sample code would be fantastic, i've having a heck of a time finding examples / tutorials for this online

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this just by calling `Where` multiple times:

```
IQueryable<Order> query = Entities.Orders;

if (this.LoggedInUser.UserId == 9)
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.Status.Equals(OrderStatus.NewOrder));
}
else if (this.LoggedInUser.UserId == 22)
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.AssignedToUserId.Equals(22));
}

List<Order> orders = query.ToList();
```

Until you start trying to *retrieve* the results, it won't contact the database.

If you *really* want to create a list, you'd need to create a `List<Expression<Func<Order, bool>>>` - they have to be expression trees rather than delegates, so that the Entity Framework can deal with them. Then you could just do:

```
foreach (var predicate in predicates)
{
    query = query.Where(predicate);
}
```

Or you could use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build up a single expression tree.

Comment: the problem with that (by my understanding) is that each query will execute against the db, i'd rather build up my where statements and then only perform 1 db query

Comment: @user630270: Your understanding is flawed :) As I wrote in my answer: "Until you start trying to retrieve the results, it won't contact the database."

Comment: Question, so as long as I use IQueryable it won't execute until i actually start accessing properties and such? Is that one of the features of the IQueryable - also, will a db query be made at this line: IQueryable<Order> query = Entities.Orders; ? Or only at accessing of properties- thanks again

Comment: @user630270: Not just IQueryable - the same is true for LINQ to Objects too. And no, `Entities.Orders` doesn't make a query to the database - it starts *building* a query, effectively.

Comment: The expression will be evaluated (and the query executed) when you start accessing the result e.g. by iterating, accessing the first element or calling for instance `.ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

Jon gave - of course - the answer how to do this better.

But for your original point, and why this won't work:

It is not dificult to apply the hole list (just do

```
x => orderFunctions.All(f => f(x))
```

) but you will not get any SQL-love from this - meaning you will get an error because EF cannot know what to do with the all (or whatever you will code there).
You would have to query all entries (with ToList, or ToArray) and after this it would work ... but without performance ;)

Comment: ... better use Jons answer ;) (maybe give some upvote for the demo? :D )